# Can I use OIDC flow for Facebook Login for Bussines?

Tags: facebook-login

I'm following this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/oidc-token.

Question is -  can I use oidc login flow for Facebook Bussines Login?